# How to send value from view to controller?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

When logging in, the system will retrieve information from that account and show it through the view page, which when we want to press a button to another page to display the information on that page by removing the information on the view page. How is it written? The information here refers to the logged-in user ID.

```
 <a href="<?php echo site_url('data/data_member/data_member($MEM_ID)') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-plus"></i> History user</a>
```

This is the controller.

```
public function data_member($MEM_ID)
{
    $data = $this->member_model->data_member($MEM_ID);
    $this->load->view("containner/headofadmin");
    $this->load->view("containner/headerofadmin");
    $this->load->view('data/data_member',$data);
}
```

I use Codeigniter and PHP to write it.

Comment: you can use sessions, so that some values that you need persists

Comment: Do you have a preview that can be viewed?

Comment: you can consult the manual about it https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html when the user successfully login, just save it in session. anything that you stored in session can be accessed via your controller, and just simply pass it back on your view for you to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CodeIgniter** has its own [Session Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)

(1). First, load session library in your config.php File.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

(2). In your controller.php create an array to store your session data.

```
$new_data = array( 
             'username' => 'John',
             'email' => 'john@example.com'
             );
             
$this->session->set_userdata($new_data);
```

(3). retrieve from session:-

```
$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
```